# struggling to update field from a map

Tags: apex, batch, map

Having a little issue when working with a map and performing a field update in my apex code.
I'm writing a batch that updates a field on the Contact object based upon a field on a custom object (lets call it Custom__c). I stored the Contact Id and the custom object using a map. I wish to get the field using a relationship query `Different_Custom__r.field_i_need__c` but I keep getting an error so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

Here's my code-

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<PAO__c> scope) { 
    Set<Id> conIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id, Custom__c> updateConsMap = new Map<Id, Custom__c>();
    
    for(Custom__c custom : [SELECT Id, Contact__c, PAO__c, POA__r.field_i_need__c FROM Custom__c WHERE POA__c IN :scope])            
            conIdSet.add(custom.Contact__c);
            updateConsMap.put(custom.Contact__c, custom);
        }
    
    List<Contact> conList= new List<Contact>([SELECT Id, field_to_update__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :conIdSet]);
    
    if(!conIdSet.isEmpty()) {
        for(Contact con :conList) {
            Contact c = new Contact();
            c.Id = con.Id;
            c.field_to_update__c = updateConsMap.get(custom.Contact__c).Policy_Allocation_Option__r.Performance_Lock_Date__c; <---- help here!
            conList.add(c);
    }
        update conList;

    }
```

this particular error i'm getting is `Variable does not exist: custom`. I'm not sure why the variable doesnt exist when its defined above... Also, is this going to function correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to retrieve the value from the map using the contact id but `custom` is not in scope at this line:

```
c.field_to_update__c = updateConsMap.get(custom.Contact__c).Policy_Allocation_Option__r.Performance_Lock_Date__c;
```

Within that loop, `con` is your contact reference from the list.

```
for (Contact con :conList) {
    Contact c = new Contact();
    c.Id = con.Id;
    c.field_to_update__c = updateConsMap.get(con.Id).Policy_Allocation_Option__r.Performance_Lock_Date__c;
    conList.add(c);
}
```

That said, there's likely a problem here. You're iterating `conList` and then adding new contact instances into this same list. Performing the update will throw an exception about duplicate ids.

Rather than adding a new contact, simply set the field on the `con` reference and then `update conList`.

```
for (Contact con :conList) {
    con.field_to_update__c = updateConsMap.get(con.Id).Policy_Allocation_Option__r.Performance_Lock_Date__c;
}

update conList;
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch. +1

Comment: perfect, thank you so much!